# Splice removes only last element in array

Tags: javascript, flux, alt, immutable.js

I'm having a small issue with React (still new to it). I have an array of Results. These Results have nested Bookings, also in an array, and the latter is what I'm manipulating.

When User creates Booking, everything goes as expected - `findIndex` gets the correct Result element and modifies its Bookings array accordingly.

However, when I want to "Unbook", it only finds the last Result in the array, and `findIndex` is always `-1` (so I haven't even gotten to the Bookings part, because the Result index I get is wrong).

The code is similar, my items all have unique keys, and I don't understand what could be the problem (using Alt as Flux implementation)?

Here is what happens on Create:

```
onCreateBookingSuccess(data) {
    let resultIndex = this.results.findIndex((result) => result.id === data.id);
    this.results.update(resultIndex, (result) => result.bookings.push(data));
    toastr.info('Booked! User will receive notification.');
  }
```

And on delete:

```
onDestroyBookingSuccess(data) {
    let resultIndex = this.results.findIndex((result) => result.id === data.id);
    var myBooking;
    this.results.map((result) => {
      myBooking = result.bookings.findIndex((booking) => booking.id === data.booking);
    });
    this.results.update(resultIndex, (result) => result.bookings.splice(myBooking,1));
    toastr.warning('Unbooked! User will receive notification.');
  }
```

My object:

```
<Result key={result.id} id={result.id} bookings={result.bookings} />
```

As I mentioned, the first operation goes as planned, everything is modified as it should. The issue with the second op starts from the very beginning, when `resultIndex` returns `-1`.

Comment: is 'data' passed in correctly in Destroy?

Comment: @luanped Should be correct, yes. I'm seeing the return I want to see in the "Network" panel of Chrome with the data of the destroyed entry returned. Here's the method from the Actions:

`deleteBookingFor(bookingId) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/booking/' + bookingId,
      type: 'DELETE'
    })
      .done((data) => {
        this.actions.destroyBookingSuccess(data);
      })
      .fail((jqXhr) => {
        this.actions.destroyBookingFail(jqXhr);
      });
  }`

(sorry, comments format code pretty badly) - and the Ajax method is a REST method, so the DB destroy works fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be here:

```
var myBooking;
this.results.map((result) => {
  myBooking = result.bookings.findIndex((booking) => booking.id === data.booking);
});
```

You’re *always* assigning to `myBooking`, even when the index is not found (`-1`) after having already found it, so it’s equivalent to `this.results.last().bookings.findIndex(...)`. Really you only want to get the (first?) value that’s not `-1`:

```
var myBooking = this.results.map((result) => {
  myBooking = result.bookings.findIndex((booking) => booking.id === data.booking);
}).find((index) => index != -1);
```

Also, consider renaming `myBooking` to better indicate it’s an index and not the actual record.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Might be, but the issue occurs earlier than that. The `let resultIndex = this.results.findIndex((result) => result.id === data.id);` in the 'onDestroyBookingSuccess' action is the one returning "-1", while the same code works perfectly in the 'onCreateBookingSuccess' action - that's why this is puzzling me...